# React router, client side rendering (only)

Tags: reactjs, rendering, client-side, react-router

I'm using react router to navigate through my application, but I don't want react router to make a call to the server, is that possible?

Comment: Yes react-router does not interface with any server.. nothing in the react stack does it's all client side

Comment: @azium In my application it does!

Comment: I don't get what your question is then..

Comment: How are you transitioning routes? If you set `location.href` directly, you will hit the server, but if you use `browserHistory.push()`, it will not. That said, if you hit a route directly (i.e. type the address and hit enter). It will hit your server. in that case, you need your server to serve up `index.html`. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Hash history](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory).

```
import { Router, Route }  from 'react-router'
import createHashHistory  from 'history/lib/createHashHistory'

<Router history={ createHashHistory({ queryKey: false }) }>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

If you don't want to use the hash history (which appends a `#` to the url), use the [Link Component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link) which will correctly navigate the App based on the history type passed.